# How to calculate orientation of line segments using open source GIS?

Tags: open-source-gis, vector

I'd like to calculate the orientation of line segments relative to north direction using open source tools. Which tools or functions would you recommend?

Comment: Just to note unlike your question about line lengths this can be done mathematically really without the direct need of a GIS system (especially if the coordinates are projected). The line lengths is more difficult mainly because the longest line is not necessarily from one vertex to another vertex.

Comment: @Andy W.: Yes, I figured that a GIS wouldn't be necessary, but it would be nice to know if it's already implemented somewhere :) I'm feeling lazy.

Comment: agreed, no need to do more any more work than absolutely necessary

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To get an angle from a line you just need to find the angle of the normalized direction. The Atan2 function is available on every computing platform I have used, even calculators. The basic idea is to get a normalized vector for the direction of that line then get the angle.

```
var normal = line.Direction.GetNormalized();
```

For your case since you need it to be north (+y hopefully) relative and possibly clockwise you could reverse the inputs to Atan2 like so:

```
var radians = Atan2(normal.x,normal.y);
```

And if you need counter-clockwise negate the result of Atan2. For degrees just multiply by 180 then divide by `PI`. Also note that when the result is negative you can add `2*PI`.

```
if(radians < 0) { radians += 6.28... }
```

Edited: to correct an error for counter-clockwise.

Note: only works if `North` is always `up`.

Comment: Open source version: http://gist.github.com/604912

Comment: Hey, I just found out I could really benefit from this code in my task. One thing, I have no idea which is the programming language it is written, could you please tell me so that I can use it? Is it java, javascript, c? thanks in advance!

Comment: @umbe1987 That code is JavaScript but it should be easy to translate to any language as it is a simple function.

Answer (score 4):

To muddy the water a bit: what projection are your line segments in? The answer depends! If you're it's a Mercator projection, Dandy's answer works. (In a Mercator, lines are rhumb -- by definition, holding the same compass direction for their length.)

In general, however, a line on a map will not correspond to the same compass direction (azimuth) along its entire length -- so your question doesn't always have an answer.

It might be acceptable for you to just assume your lines are rhumb, or to calculate two directions -- one at each endpoint, or to compromise and calculate the direction at the midpoint . . . .

Comment: Thank you for your comment, you're right. Luckily the lines are in a Mercator projection.

Comment: Should have clarified that a bit better. That would definitely take the easy out of it.

Answer (score 1):

GRASS GIS (http://grass.osgeo.org/) offers native directed graphs (i.e. vector lines). See "Vector network" screenshots [here](https://grass.osgeo.org/learn/gallery/#&gid=1&pid=45). Furthermore, there is the [m.cogo](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass-stable/manuals/m.cogo.html) tool included.

Comment: So m.cogo adds the orientation (and distance) to attribute table or will it just output the same format it needs for the reverse operation (bearing + distance to coordinates)?