# Selecting polygons by number of sides

Tags: arcgis-10.0, polygon, features

I'm using ArcGIS 10 to build some figures for a journal article.  One is a figure of an unstructured finite element mesh of triangles spanning the western Atlantic Ocean.  I exported this mesh from SMS to a polygon shapefile where each triangle is a polygon and added it to my ArcGIS map.  It looks great; however, the islands (such as Haiti and Cuba) are also polygons in the shapefile.  I would like to remove them without manually selecting them all.

**Is there a way I can select only the polygons with more than 3 sides in order to delete them?**

Answer (score 6):

In the attribute table, compute a numeric field with the Python expression

```
!shape.getpart(0).count!
```

The triangles will all have values of 4 (three vertices plus a duplicate of the first one to close the polygon).  The islands almost surely will have more than 4: select them based on this count and delete them, or (more safely) set the layer's definition to include only 4-vertex polygons.

Comment: That's much more efficient than my solution. So simple.

Comment: Thanks, @Jeff.  It's worth noting that yours is more reliable (+1): if there exist multi-part polygons whose first part (.getpart(0)) is a triangle, they will be incorrectly retained.  This seems highly unlikely in the present context but future readers will want to be aware of the issue.  The problem can be solved with a bit of Python coding in the Field Calculator: you need to check whether *all* the parts of each feature have four vertices.

Comment: Incidentally, when setting out to answer this question I had no idea what the correct FC expression was, but I knew that ArcGIS *had* to provide access to the features as lists-of-lists-of-points.  A little poking around in the FC help pointed the way, syntactically, and then Googling "arcgis 10 geometry attribute python" quickly turned up [ESRI help](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=The%20geometry%20object) documenting the "Geometry Object" and suggesting the use of `getpart`.  A couple quick tests with a throwaway shapefile verified that it works.

Answer (score 2):

If the triangles are uniform then the areas could be used as a selection criteria. If not, my first inclination would be to do this programmatically.  However, you could do this just using geoprocessing tools as follows:

1. Use the **Feature Vertices To Points** tool to convert all polygons vertices to a point layer.
2. Open the attribute table for the resulting point layer, right click on the **ORIG_FID** field and summarize.  This will give you a table with each unique **OBJECTID** in the original polygon layer along with the count of vertices associated with that feature.
3. Join the summary table to the original polygon layer based on the **OBJECTID** in the polygon layer and the **ORIG_FID** field in the summary table.
4. Select By Attributes from the the polygon layer where the **summarytable.Cnt_ORIG_FID** field is > 4.  This will select all polygons with greater than 4 vertices.  You need to use > 4 to account for the vertex at the start and end of the triangles.

Answer (score 0):

Is your goal to select polygons with more than 3 sides, or just figure out how to excluse your islands?  While this doesn't exactly answer how to select a polygon with more than 3 sides, it may get you the result you are after...

Do you have the source polygons for the island layer?  If so you could do a "Select By Location" to extract their locations.

If you don't have the actual source of the island polygons, what about using a reasonable facsimile to create a polygon (islands) centroid, then use the centroid to "Select By Location" to find the polygons of your mesh that intersect the centroid points?