# How to determine ring orientation from lat/long coordinate points?

Tags: geometry, coordinates, direction

We have some set of point coordinates in lat/long which contribute to a polygon. From this set how do we determine the polygon is clockwise or anticlockwise?

Comment: Given that there are valid cases where a single polygon can be counter clockwise, there's no real way to tell if a polygon is 'clockwise' or 'counterclockwise' without some level of implied knowledge.  However, what you're looking for is the 'envelope angle' of your polygon.  If it's greater than 90°, then it's 'counterclockwise', otherwise 'clockwise'.  Depending on your platform, there are different ways of finding this out.  One way would be to ensure that all your data is stored in a valid format before sending it to the client.

Comment: @nagytech No, it is trivial to determine ring orientation -- Calculate the area using the trapezoid rule (or zipper algorithm); negative area is opposite orientation of positive area

Comment: Check again, I never said any operation was non-trivial.  Regardless, calculating the envelope angle is immensely more efficient than calculating the area of a polygon.

Comment: You wrote "there's no real way to tell if a polygon is 'clockwise' or 'counterclockwise' without some level of implied knowledge", which is incorrect.

Comment: Here is a [discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165647/how-to-determine-if-a-list-of-polygon-points-are-in-clockwise-order) on stack overflow.

Comment: Related: http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/62884 http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/3729 http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/119150 -- however, I hope that someone adds an answer describing the algorithms available for this fundamental GIS concept, so that this could be made into a canonical Q&A.